# Are there APIs in Autodesk Forge for T-spline Surfaces?

Tags: autodesk-forge

We want to use Autodesk Forge for developing parametric modellers for the Maritime industry using T-spline technology. We are wondering if there API in Forge for the usage of T-spline surfaces.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Today, the only Forge service which uses T-Spline is [Design Automation](https://forge.autodesk.com/api/design-automation-cover-page/) for Inventor.

Design Automation for Inventor is a service which allows you to run Autodesk Inventor kernel on the cloud. Your Inventor plug-in running on Inventor will be able to use Nurbs, T-Spline, Brep, iLogic, ... APIs.